# Display diagonal rows elements of a table in a single row using sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have one database table consisting of 5 fields , one is of data type int and rest four are of type string.

```
ref_num field 1         field 2        field 3             field 4
38      Test_user1      NULL            NULL                NULL
38      NULL          Network_L2_P1     NULL                NULL
38      NULL            NULL            user_1              NULL
38      NULL            NULL            NULL               Test_user
39      Test_user1      NULL            NULL                 NULL
39      NULL           Test_user2       NULL                 NULL
39      NULL            NULL           Test_user3            NULL
39      NULL            NULL            NULL               Test_user4
```

i want these diagonally arranged field values to come in single row. like this-

```
ref_num    field 1        field 2         field 3         field 4
38      Test_user1     Network_L2_P1      user_1      Test_user5
39      Test_user1      Test_user2      Test_user3    Test_user4
```

How to create the sql query for this?

we can have n no. of fields and it could be any name and it could be any ref_num

i tried using max function max() on 4 string fields and tried running query using group by clause to get the expected result. The actual challenge is these names in the four fields can be any name. So we cant use max() all the time and max() returns int value for string values in our case . Also rank() function is also not supported in our case.

Comment: Try this with `GROUP BY ref_num` and `WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL...so on`

Comment: these 4 columns are fixed..?

Comment: @DarkRob name listed in the 4 columns can be changed rest all would be the same.

Comment: @Mahesh tried with that too but it didn't worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = (
        SELECT '
        ' +
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' +  (
            'SUBSTRING(
            (
                SELECT '',''+ST1.[' + c.name + ']  AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.testTemp ST1
                WHERE ST1.[Tid] = ST2.[Tid] 
                ORDER BY ST1.[Tid]
                FOR XML PATH ('''')
            ), 2, 1000) '
            ) +  ' AS [' + c.name  +']'     

           FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id] and c.name not in ( 'ref_num')   --- here column name of your id column
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, 'SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Tid], ') + '
        FROM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + '] as ST2 ' -- select *
        FROM sys.objects o
        WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
            AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
            AND [name] = 'testTemp'   ---- your table name
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

This is generic solutions for `n` number of columns.

Mark it as accepted if works for you....

Answer (score 0):

your problem is solved...you can pick multiple column.....

```
SELECT t1.ref_num,
field1 =REPLACE( (SELECT field1 AS [data()]
FROM tblDiagonal t2
WHERE t2.ref_num = t1.ref_num
ORDER BY ref_num
FOR XML PATH('')
), ' ', ','),

field2 =REPLACE( (SELECT field2 AS [data()]
FROM tblDiagonal t2
WHERE t2.ref_num = t1.ref_num
ORDER BY ref_num
FOR XML PATH('')
), ' ', ','),

field3 =REPLACE( (SELECT field3 AS [data()]
FROM tblDiagonal t2
WHERE t2.ref_num = t1.ref_num
ORDER BY ref_num
FOR XML PATH('')
), ' ', ','), 

field4 =REPLACE( (SELECT field4 AS [data()]
FROM tblDiagonal t2
WHERE t2.ref_num = t1.ref_num
ORDER BY ref_num
FOR XML PATH('')
), ' ', ',')          
FROM tblDiagonal t1
GROUP BY ref_num ;
```

[image: Output]